# Solving damped wave equation given boundary conditions and initial conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

How would you go about solving the damped equation:

$ u_{tt} = u_{xx} - u_t $

$0 < x < 1,$ $t > 0$

With intial conditions: $ u(x,0) = \sin(2 \pi x)$ and $u_t(x,0) = 0$

With boundary conditions: $u(0,t) = 0$ and $ u(1,t) = 0$

So far, I am able to separate $u(x,t) = \phi(x)G(t)$, and solve: $ \frac{G'' + G'}{G} = \frac{\phi''}{\phi} = -\lambda  $ to get $\lambda_n = (n\pi)^2$ and $\phi_n = \sin(n \pi x)$ but run into a dead end afterward.

Comment: I don't think you meant the equation you wrote: it is just the heat equation $2 u_t = u_{xx}$.

Comment: Yes thank you @RobertIsrael I have edited the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Since the Fourier series for $u(x,0)$ has only the one term ($n=2$), we may take 
$\phi(x) = \sin(2\pi x)$, $\lambda = 4 \pi^2$.  The solutions for $G(t)$ can be written as 
$e^{-t/2} (c_1 \cos(\alpha t) + c_2 \sin(\alpha t)) $ where $\alpha = \sqrt{4\pi^2-1/4}$.  Then determine $c_1$ and $c_2$ so the initial conditions are satisfied.